# Lock free list with sync_val_compare_and_swap

Tags: c++, lock-free, compare-and-swap

I'm trying to provide a thread safe way to update an object.  I've seen a few posts about it, but nothing that answers my question 100%.

What I want to do is maintain a pointer called 'm_First' to point at my data.  If someone calls get, I deference that pointer, returning a reference to the object it points at.

If Someone calls set, passing in a pointer to a new object, we add that pointer to our list and update m_First to point at the new object.

I store the objects in a vector, so that we can clean up memory when we are done.

Currently I have these members defined:

```
std::vector<MyObject*> m_List;
const MyObject* m_First;
```

First is intialized like this.
    m_First = m_List.back();

I want to allow multiple threads to read m_First, while multiple threads also write to m_First.

My class has two methods

```
MyObject& getMyObject() {return *m_First;}

void setMyObject(MyObject* newObj) {

  m_List.push_back(newObj); // add to list so we can later cleanup mem

  do {
    Node* oldHead = m_First;
  } while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(m_First, *oldHead, *newObj));
}
```

What I am wondering is, returning *m_First in the get method thread safe.  i.e. Can I safely dereference this and return the reference to the object, while another thread is attempting to update m_First, or do I need to use some sort of atomic method for reading m_First.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Comment: But... this looks like a push-only freelist, no?  how do you ever get hold of the objects you've pushed onto the list, when get only returns the point of the current head element, without popping it from the list?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that the value is read from memory and not from a register, you will need to do an atomic read.

There are different ways to achieve this. On some systems reading an aligned, word-size value through a volatile pointer cast like `*(const volatile MyObject*)p` will work. But since you are already using builtin atomic operations you could just make use of something like `__sync_add_and_fetch` with an add of 0.

Comment: From what I can tell __sync_add_and_fetch will only work with integer types.  The volatile pointer cast may work.  I'll try it out,

Answer (score 0):

> I want to allow multiple threads to read m_First, while multiple threads also write to m_First.

How will multiple threads write to `m_First`? If it's through `setMyObject` then they will all modify the `m_List` vector concurrently, which will be a data race and almost certainly corrupt the vector.